# Solving an sqlplus query

Tags: sql, sqlplus

Given below are two relation schemas:

Book(id, title, author, pubid, year, price, referid)

Publisher(pubid, pubname, headoffice, contact)

'id' is the primary key for Book and pubid is the primary key for 'Publisher' as well as a foreign key.

Q. Find the book id, title, referenced title and referenced publisher name.

help me answer this query...I'm trying hard but to no avail

Comment: What was the error message you received? What was wrong about the result set your query produced?

Comment: Is column `referid`, in database table `Book` the ID of another book in the same table?

Comment: Maybe you can [edit] your question and post some sample rows from both the `Book` table and the `Publisher` table?

Comment: @Abra, yeah. referid is the id of other books in the corresponding table.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a homework question and not like you've invested much time into solving this query on your own but this should get you started.  Please edit your question to clarify if it's something more specific you're having issues:

```
SELECT
    Book.id,
    Book.title,
    Publisher.pubname

FROM Book
INNER JOIN Publisher
    ON Book.pubid = Publisher.pubid
```

Answer (score 0):

This query should do

```
SELECT Book.id, Book.title, Refbook.title, Refpub.pubname
FROM Book 
LEFT JOIN Book AS Refbook ON Book.referid = Refbook.id
JOIN Publisher AS Refpub ON Refpub.pubid = Refbook.pubid
```

For the next time, please give example data and a result you're looking for